# Javascript is working fine but not in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works fine for me in Javascript.

```
function check_u() {
    var errormessage = document.getElementById("errorname");
    var user = document.forms["login"]["user"].value;
    if (user == null || user == "") {
        errormessage.innerHTML = "Please enter your user id";
    } else {
        errormessage.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
function check_p() {
    var errormessage = document.getElementById("errorpass");
    var pass = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
    if (pass == null || pass == "") {
        errorShow.innerHTML = "Password cannot be blank";
    } else {
        errorShow.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

My html is :

```
<input type="text" name="user" autocomplete="off" onBlur="check_u()" />
<input type="text" name="password" autocomplete="off" onBlur="check_p()" />
<div id="errorname" />
```

I have written an alternative for this code in jQuery. In JavaScript it works fine but in jQuery when I don't enter any input first time it is showing error message. I enter some value to it then it clears the error message. Now if I am leaving the input blank the error message doen't show up. Here is my jQuery code:

```
function check_u(){
            var fieldValue = $("input[name=user]").val();
    if(fieldValue==""||fieldValue==null){
                    $("#errorname").html('<div id = "error_left"></div>'+
       '<div id = "error_right"><p>This is a required field</p></div>');
            }else{
                    $("#errorname").hide();
            }
        }
```

Why, if on repeated calls, does my errorname div not show up?

Does .hide() do more than just clear out the div?

Comment: Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: have you referenced the jQuery library?

Comment: Your method name seems to be wrong `onBlur="check_u()` and `checkUser`

Comment: when I don't enter any input first time it is showing error message..what is the error message it is showing?

Comment: you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: No errors are showing in the console. I have edited the function here to avoid ambiguity. My Error message in the sense my custom error message when user leaves a field blank.

Comment: A jsfiddle may help...

Comment: _"Does .hide() do more than just clear out the div?"_ - It doesn't clear out the div at all, it _hides_ it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the javascript else clause, you are clearing the contents, but in the jQuery clause you are hiding the entire error element.

Instead of

```
$("#errorname").hide()
```

try

```
$("#errorname").html("")
```

Comment: This shouldn't really matter. Clearing it or not showing it isn't his problem. His problem is the event isn't firing.

Comment: When it is hidden what ever manipulation I do and change the content will it be visible?

Comment: Actually Jason is right. If you hide it, you're setting "display:none;" so it'll never show up again. You'd have to call a .show() to bring it back. Or, just not call hide, and just clear it out.

Comment: @JackMarchetti: If I will use .show() in my if statement then will it cause any problem if the div is not hidden before

Comment: No calling show on a visible field will cause no problem, but just use Jason's example of setting the HTML to "". That'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show `errorname` after setting the html

```
$("#errorname").html('<div id = "error_left"></div>'+
   '<div id = "error_right"><p>This is a required field</p></div>').show();
```

You are hiding the `errorname` div in case of a valid entry, then if value becomes invalid then you need to set the error message and set the visibility to of the div.

demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V40mzQv9Xc9UDpzBTlPv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your onblur is calling `check_u()` but your other jQuery example's function name is `checkUser()`

Comment: No. I have check_u in my program but I have edited here to checkUser to avoid ambiguity. Someone may say that I am using same function number twice.

Comment: Are you referencing the jQuery library? I took your code, put it into a page and it works for me.

Comment: Jason said I have a problem with the HTML and HIDE function. It might be my solution.